# in Jax-rs, how can I render null values as empty strings in the json output

Tags: java, json, jax-rs

I currently have a JPA entity like this

```
@XmlNullPolicy(emptyNodeRepresentsNull = true, nullRepresentationForXml = XmlMarshalNullRepresentation.EMPTY_NODE )
@XmlRootElement
@Entity
public class Entity implements Serializable {
   @id
   @Column
   private Long id;
   @Column
   private String field2;
   @Column 
   private BigDecimal field3;
   @Column
   private BigDecimal field4;
```

When I return the entity in a jax-rs web service I've got :

```
{ "id" : 12345 , "field2" : "Hello world" , "field3" : null, "field4" : null }
```

I would like to have an output like

```
{ "id" : 12345 , "field2" : "Hello world" , "field3" : "", "field4" : "" }
```

What is the best idiom to achieve this ?

I am using weblogic 12c and my JAXB implementation is eclipselink-moxy.

Comment: You can implement a customer serializer where you can set the null values to " "; public class YourClassSerializer extends JsonSerializer<YourClass> {}

Answer (score 1):

I personally think that it is not a good practice. You are loosing information when using an empty `String`. `null` means that it is not set and the empty `String` object means that it is set with empty value. I think that the client should handle this, but if you want to loose that kind of information You can create custom serialisation like the one mentioned [here](https://github.com/jasonray/jersey-starterkit/wiki/Serializing-a-POJO-to-xml-or-json-using-JAXB).

Comment: I will consider your suggestion, although sometimes we cannot choose the format.

Comment: If it is really needed you can create an adapter like this: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/xml/bind/annotation/adapters/XmlJavaTypeAdapter.html It also works for `JSON`.